# What is the best tag for a question about working at NASA?

Tags: discussion, tags

This [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19964/does-nasa-have-an-army-and-air-force-exchange-service) asks if NASA has an 'on base' department store the way the Army and Air force do. Unless this question is going to be marked off-topic, it seems we might need some better tags for it. Currently 'food' and 'ground-station' don't seem to cover the question.

Is there or should there be a 'crew', 'personnel', 'work-place', 'working-conditions' or 'employment' tag for such a question?

Some other questions about working in the space industry:

[Which are the chances of a programmer without engineering-related degrees to work in space industry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/which-are-the-chances-of-a-programmer-without-engineering-related-degrees-to-wor)

[Do chemical engineers play a significant role in space exploration?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5898/do-chemical-engineers-play-a-significant-role-in-space-exploration)

[Space exploration career opportunities for Europeans?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18211/space-exploration-career-opportunities-for-europeans)

[For one way missions to any planet is it planned to pay astronauts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15148/for-one-way-missions-to-any-planet-is-it-planned-to-pay-astronauts)

[Does NASA hire foreign nationals as astronauts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10548/does-nasa-hire-foreign-nationals-as-astronauts)

Answer (score 1):

The question, well, in question, is currently tagged [nasa](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nasa) [food](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) [ground-station](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-station).

I can't speak for the second two, but given that the question is asking *specifically* about NASA, not working in the space industry in general, it seems to me that [nasa](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nasa) applies very well. According to the tag wiki excerpt, that particular tag should be used for:

> Questions pertaining to activities of the National Aeronautics and Space Administration, a United States government agency that deals with space exploration and research.

...which seems to be what the question is about. That tag is well established on the site with 190 questions thus tagged and 9 followers.

I honestly fail to see how [food](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) and [ground-station](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-station) help categorize that particular question. If it was just me, I'd probably delete those two tags and keep just [nasa](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nasa), but now that it's up for discussion on Meta I'll keep my hands off of the *edit tags* feature for a while and see just how the community feels...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample list of questions that might be affected, I see several tagged as [career](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career). I think this is a good enough tag for most of the questions I was originally asking about.
[career](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) only has 4 questions, no wiki, and no synonyms. Perhaps it is in need of some synonyms like 'work place' though I'm not sure that is an appropriate use of synonyms.

Comment: That's not really the purpose of synonyms. See the [Help Center](http://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms): `Whenever you see questions being repeatedly tagged with the wrong or incorrect tag -- or multiple tags that mean the same thing -- it's a good idea to propose a tag synonym. The goal is to avoid manually editing the tags on every post by making the retagging automatic for common tag mistakes.`

Comment: That said, if you see an existing tag that seems to function similarly to career, you could propose to make it a synonym.